# Appliyng data augmentation to all but one class in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I have a dataset with 8 categories and I'm currently performing data augmentation in all the classes with the following code:

```
train_dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None,horizontal_flip=True,rotation_range=90,
                                   vertical_flip=True)

train_generator = train_dataGen.flow_from_directory(directory="./new_distr/train",
                                                    class_mode="categorical",
                                                    target_size=(224, 224),
                                                    batch_size=32)
```

This works perfectly, but I noticed that one of my classes represents half of all the images so I don't want to augment it.

Do I need to create 2 different generators and then fuse them or is there another way? If it is the first case I have already created the 2 different generators but I don't know how to fuse them. One of my doubts regarding this is what would happen to the labels if I fuse the generators? Here is the code of the creation of the 2 generators:

```
train_others = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None,horizontal_flip=True,rotation_range=90,
                                   vertical_flip=True)
train_cats= ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None)

train_generator_cats = train_cats.flow_from_directory(directory="./new_distr/train_pad_cc/cats",
                                                     class_mode="categorical",                                                
                                                     batch_size=32)
train_generator_others = train_others .flow_from_directory(directory="./new_distr/train_pad_cc/others",
                                                     class_mode="categorical",                                                
                                                     batch_size=32)
```

In case anyone wants to check the rest of my code regarding the creation of the Convolutional neural network, it is here:

```
Resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = tf.keras.Sequential(Resnet)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
History= model.fit(train_generator, epochs = 50).history
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to use 2 generators and you can iterate with the help of chain method

following your example :

```
from itertools import chain

train_others = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None,horizontal_flip=True,rotation_range=90,
                                   vertical_flip=True)
train_cats= ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None)

train_generator_cats = train_cats.flow_from_directory(directory="./new_distr/train_pad_cc/cats",
                                                     class_mode="categorical",                                                
                                                     batch_size=32)
train_generator_others = train_others .flow_from_directory(directory="./new_distr/train_pad_cc/others",
                                                     class_mode="categorical",                                                
                                                     batch_size=32)

merged_generator = chain(train_generator_cats, train_generator_others)

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
History= model.fit(merged_generator, epochs = 50).history
```

Comment: But wouldn't the labels conflict? train_cats would make labels from 0 to 6 and train_others  would use the label 0. So there wouldn't be a label "7" or does the chain method changes that?

Comment: Also is it normal to appear an unknown number of iterations per epoch? Only happens when I do this

Comment: @Bia my bad on labels part , basicly you can pass labels to label argument in one hot encoded way check : https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/ labels list of same dir size

Comment: @Bia a another alternative suggestion i would give is augment your images using library like augmentor for example https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor which generate the augmented images in new folder and then you can use single data loader, this way you have visualize images and not just create them on memeory